# Extra blank space on answers near the end of the list

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When I am reading answers to a question with many answers, the further down the list of questions I go, the more blank space at the end of each answer is there.  After about 5 answers, you start getting about a  screen full of nothing but white space at the end of the answer.

I'm on a Motorola razr maxx, running cyanogenmod
This screenshot is from the latest example I've seen, on rpg.se, but it occurred on Stack overflow also.

Top of the example answer:
[image]

Bottom of the example answer:
[image]

Here's the question from the screenshots
[How can I suggest the DM stop trying to kill us?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62911/10177)

Comment: Your connection is probably slow. Give it time to load, and it will most likely be fine.

Comment: Hmm it's not really acting like there's a slow connection... I've got pretty good service here, and have actually been reading the answers above it, so it's had plenty of time to load. Reading my statement it may not be obvious that I am actually seeing the full answer, there's just also a whole lot of blank space at the bottom. It seems to be worse when the answer itself is also long

Comment: Can you post a link? I tried to repro with some posts here on MSE and it's all fine.

Comment: I added the link, the answer by "grizzled" is the most obvious

Comment: No repro. All answers started blank, but within few seconds were filled with contents. Can you try this with a WiFi connection enabled and active, just to rule out slow connection?

Comment: I can try it from home this afternoon.

Comment: OK, I tried again from my home network, with the same results.  I updated the screenshots to give a more complete example of what it looks like

Comment: Weird - fear we'll have to wait for a dev then to see this and hopefully he/she will be able to reproduce and fix.